# R gridSVG package - MultiPanel gapminder - Simon Potter's code getting an error during execution

Tags: r

I am trying to run the code (that can be downloaded here https://sjp.co.nz/projects/gridsvg/demos/gapminder-multi/), which should create an animation of the gapminder data using the R package gridSVG.

1. I downloaded the files

[image]

2. In the 3 R files, I inserted a line in which I set the working directory to the folder that contains the above files setwd("my working directory")
3. I executed the gapminder.R file and I get the following 2 errors:

[image]

...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to clear how it should work, but without success.

I haven't advanced skills in R and, by my opinion, R Documentation of grid and gridSVG packages is poor.

People need more examples, I think.

Look, on the page by your [link](https://sjp.co.nz/projects/gridsvg/demos/gapminder-multi/) you can find an e-mail of the [author](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/people/pmur002), who made this visual. Maybe, you write a letter to him?

Maybe, it worked in the previous version of this package? Or we have curve hands, I don't know.

But look:

```
grid.set(gPath, newGrob, strict = FALSE, grep = FALSE,
         redraw = TRUE)
```

We should make a certain newGrob(right syntax is...?) and pass to animateGrob?
[image]

Comment: re grid documentation. The package author includes a ton of resources at their website: https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ and bits of code fro mtheir book : https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/rgraphics.html

Comment: @user20650 Yes, I saw these things. But how one can find there a needed info. Tough, I think. I love the help pane in RStudio, it is really convenient

Comment: @user20650 P.S. Can you look at my bountied question? Maybe, have some thoughts...

Comment: @manro: I appreciate you trying to help but I am not sure we're any closer to an answer.

Comment: @ColorStatistics If you hesitate to write him, i'll can try)

Comment: @ColorStatistics I added you to chat room

Answer (score 0):

Also stumbled at the problem that gridSVG has not been really animating.
It seems gridSVG has not been updated to the ggplot change that must have happened in the meantime related to the grobbing:

Currently, ggplot is lazy-evaluating and `grid.ls()` and all other grid functions will print only top-level `layout` grob versus the grob tree gridSVG expects.

In order to fix it in the gapminder example one has to add `grid.force()` every time grobs are to be parsed:

e.g.,

```
g = ggplot(data=all) +
      geom_point(aes(x=X1950.x, y=X1950.y, size=radius,
                     colour=continent),
                 shape=16, alpha=.5) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1, 9),
                         name="Fertility\n(# children per woman)") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(10, 90),
                         name="Life Expectancy (at birth)") +
      scale_colour_manual(values=continentCols) +
      theme(legend.position="none") +
      scale_size(range=c(1, 20))

# add grid.force(), otherwise grid.ls() and all other grid functions 
# will see only top-level 'layout', there will be no tree to traverse.
grid.force()
# grid.ls()

# Try to animate
grid.set("geom_point", grep=TRUE,
         animateGrob(grid.get("geom_point", grep=TRUE),
                     duration=20,
                     x=t(ggplotScaleX(as.matrix(all[xCols]),
                                      1, 9)),
                     y=t(ggplotScaleY(as.matrix(all[yCols]),
                                      10, 90))))

...
```

Also add the same change in the `ggplotScale.R`

```
calcGGplotScale <- function() {
# Produce a ggplot with two points at
    print(ggplot(data.frame(x=0:1, y=0:1)) +
          geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)))
# Get the points grob
    grid.force()  # Add this to actually evaluate the grob-tree 
# so the subsequent call makes sense.
    grob <- grid.get("geom_point", grep=TRUE)
# Determine extent of scaled region
    list(xrange=as.numeric(grob$x),
         yrange=as.numeric(grob$y))
}
```